# Глобальный GUI поверх всего

Tags: python, gui

Суть. Хочу сделать глобальный gui, с различными gui-элементами и скриптами для личных нужд.

Это будет выглядеть примерно так. Есть глобальный холст на весь экран, куда будут выводится различные элементы (логи, кнопки, быстрые ссылки, полезные скрипты/команды для запуска и т.п). По умолчанию он будет иметь прозрачность и не будет оказывать какого-либо влияния, но при этом я могу работать с основными программами и посматривать, что там выводится. По хоткею, например, я можно будет сделать данный холст активным и взаимодействовать с элементами на нём, либо убрать его, чтобы не мешал.

Какие есть способы на Python'e рисовать изображения, анимацию, gui поверх всех окон? Желательно кросплатформенно.

Можно ли сделать это на Qt?

P.S. Может это будет проще сделать на другом языке?

Comment: хотя мне не нравиться слово `глобальный` , 
но вы можете посмотреть в сторону `кроссплатформенного PyQt5`.

Comment: Это вам в сторону Wayland сомтреть надо, остальные такое просто так не позволят делать.